# How to upload to a bucket in App Engine in PHP?

Tags: php, upload, cloud, storage

I followed this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload

So, i wanna make it working.

Here my source code:

```
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$options = ['gs_bucket_name' => 'tkblue-dev-236414.appspot.com'];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload', $options);

require __DIR__.'/../../../../vendor/autoload.php';

$file_name = $_FILES['uploaded_files']['name'];
$temp_name = $_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name'];

echo move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "gs://tkblue-dev-236414.appspot.com/".$file_name) ;

?>

<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Files to upload: <br>
   <input type="file" name="uploaded_files" size="40">
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

When I upload from my webpage, I have no error, but the file is not imported in my bucket when I check here : https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser in my bucket

My uploaded file is not present.

Why ?